# matching line colors to legend when plotting data from multiple arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have temperature data from multiple devices on different boards, for example, on board 1 I have temperature for the PCB itself, and 3 different FETs, and similarly for boards 2 and 3.
I read the data into a dataframe, and want to plot the data together with the same color for each board tested, but with different markers for each of the devices on the boards.  For example, all the measurements from board 1 would be blue, with the PCB temp using marker '+', FET1 using marker 'v' etc.
I read the files in like this:

```
for file_name in glob.glob(path+'*.csv'):
    filename[i] = os.path.basename(file_name)
    print(filename[i])
    #x[i]= np.genfromtxt(path+ filename[i], delimiter=',',skip_header=20,usecols=(2,4,6,8))
    x[i]=pd.read_csv(path+filename[i], header=0,usecols=[2,4,6,8], skiprows=12,names=['PCB', 'FET1', 'FET2', 'FET3'])
```

and create an array of dataframes.

I then plot the different columns :

```
colors=['r','b','g','c','m']
for i in range(len(filename)):
    #plt.figure()
    plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['PCB'],5),'-+'+colors[i],label="PCB")
    plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET1'],5),'-v'+colors[i],label='FET1')
    plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET2'],5),'-x'+colors[i],label='FET2')
    plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET3'],5),'-o'+colors[i],label='FET3')
    leg=np.append(leg, filename[i][0:7])
    #plt.show()


plt.show()
plt.legend(leg)
```

[image]

The markers are correctly displayed, but as I iterated through the dataframes, the color information was lost.  How can I plot the data and arrange it so that legend uses the same color per  group of lines (as grouped by index i)?

Here's some sample data:
 file 1:

```
Name:,Data Instr INSTR 3/5/2020 11:51:59,,,,,,,,,,,,
Owner:,lab1,,,,,,,,,,,,
Comments:,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Acquisition Date:,3/5/2020 11:51,,,,,,,,,,,,
&Instrument:,34970A,Address:,ASRL11::INSTR,Modules:,1,Slot3:,34901A,,,,,,
Total Channels:,4,,,,,,,,,,,,
Channel,Name,Function,Range,Resolution,AdvSettings,Scale,Gain,Offset,Label,Test,Low,High,HWAlarm
316,PCB_CTR,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,FALSE,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1
317,Q24,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,FALSE,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1
318,Q25,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,FALSE,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1
319,Q18,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,FALSE,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1
Scan  Control:,Start Action:,Immediately,Stop Action:,User Terminated,,,,,,,,,
Scan,Time,316 <PCB_CTR> (C),Alarm 316,317 <Q24> (C),Alarm 317,318 <Q25> (C),Alarm 318,319 <Q18> (C),Alarm 319,,,,
1,3/5/2020 11:51:59:168,30.471,0,29.241,0,29.165,0,33.302,0,,,,
2,3/5/2020 11:52:01:152,32.197,0,30.634,0,30.564,0,34.819,0,,,,
3,3/5/2020 11:52:03:152,33.795,0,32.019,0,31.879,0,36.848,0,,,,
4,3/5/2020 11:52:05:152,35.315,0,33.383,0,33.236,0,38.282,0,,,,
5,3/5/2020 11:52:07:152,36.965,0,34.734,0,34.62,0,39.946,0,,,,
6,3/5/2020 11:52:09:152,38.255,0,36.054,0,35.776,0,41.18,0,,,,
7,3/5/2020 11:52:11:152,39.467,0,37.328,0,37.028,0,42.258,0,,,,
```

file 2

```
Name:,Data Instr INSTR 3/5/2020 10:03:21,,,,,,,,,,,,
Owner:,lab1,,,,,,,,,,,,
Comments:,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Acquisition Date:,3/5/2020 10:03,,,,,,,,,,,,
&Instrument:,34970A,Address:,ASRL11::INSTR,Modules:,1,Slot3:,34901A,,,,,,
Total Channels:,4,,,,,,,,,,,,
Channel,Name,Function,Range,Resolution,AdvSettings,Scale,Gain,Offset,Label,Test,Low,High,HWAlarm
316,PCB_CTR,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,FALSE,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1
317,Q24,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,FALSE,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1
318,Q25,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,FALSE,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1
319,Q18,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,FALSE,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1
Scan  Control:,Start Action:,Immediately,Stop Action:,User Terminated,,,,,,,,,
Scan,Time,316 <PCB_CTR> (C),Alarm 316,317 <Q24> (C),Alarm 317,318 <Q25> (C),Alarm 318,319 <Q18> (C),Alarm 319,,,,
1,3/5/2020 10:03:21:164,46.334,0,43.755,0,45.706,0,49.129,0,,,,
2,3/5/2020 10:03:22:149,46.997,0,44.262,0,46.35,0,49.773,0,,,,
3,3/5/2020 10:03:23:149,47.615,0,44.671,0,46.974,0,50.402,0,,,,
4,3/5/2020 10:03:24:149,48.267,0,45.229,0,47.628,0,50.879,0,,,,
5,3/5/2020 10:03:25:149,48.861,0,45.711,0,48.164,0,51.495,0,,,,
6,3/5/2020 10:03:26:149,49.455,0,46.323,0,48.783,0,51.9,0,,,,
7,3/5/2020 10:03:27:149,50.014,0,46.796,0,49.351,0,52.334,0,,,,
```

file 3

```
Name:,Data Instr INSTR 3/5/2020 13:41:06,,,,,,,,,,,,
Owner:,lab1,,,,,,,,,,,,
Comments:,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Acquisition Date:,3/5/2020 13:41,,,,,,,,,,,,
&Instrument:,34970A,Address:,ASRL11::INSTR,Modules:,1,Slot3:,34901A,,,,,,
Total Channels:,4,,,,,,,,,,,,
Channel,Name,Function,Range,Resolution,AdvSettings,Scale,Gain,Offset,Label,Test,Low,High,HWAlarm
316,PCB_CTR,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,FALSE,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1
317,Q24,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,FALSE,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1
318,Q25,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,FALSE,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1
319,Q18,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,FALSE,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1
Scan  Control:,Start Action:,Immediately,Stop Action:,User Terminated,,,,,,,,,
Scan,Time,316 <PCB_CTR> (C),Alarm 316,317 <Q24> (C),Alarm 317,318 <Q25> (C),Alarm 318,319 <Q18> (C),Alarm 319,,,,
1,3/5/2020 13:41:06:162,28.121,0,26.882,0,28.785,0,31.061,0,,,,
2,3/5/2020 13:41:08:147,30.582,0,27.873,0,30.691,0,33.024,0,,,,
3,3/5/2020 13:41:10:147,31.782,0,28.935,0,32.578,0,34.876,0,,,,
4,3/5/2020 13:41:12:147,34.003,0,30.094,0,34.247,0,36.652,0,,,,
5,3/5/2020 13:41:14:147,35.097,0,31.199,0,35.975,0,38.142,0,,,,
6,3/5/2020 13:41:16:147,36.708,0,32.334,0,37.504,0,39.721,0,,,,
7,3/5/2020 13:41:18:147,38.274,0,33.508,0,39.048,0,41.198,0,,,,
```

Thank you for the help.

**EDIT**

With the help from @ilke444's input, I got closer to what I want, but I still have issues:

```
for i in range(len(filename)):
    l=plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['PCB'],5),'-+'+colors[i],label="PCB")
    lines=np.append(lines,l[0].get_label())
    l=plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET1'],5),'-v'+colors[i],label='FET1')
    lines=np.append(lines,l[0].get_label())
    l=plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET2'],5),'-x'+colors[i],label='FET2')
    lines=np.append(lines,l[0].get_label())
    l=plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET3'],5),'-o'+colors[i],label='FET3')
    lines=np.append(lines,l[0].get_label())

    linesclr=np.append(linesclr, l)  # save color info
    names = np.append(names, filename[i][0:7])

fig.legend(lines, loc=1)
fig.legend(linesclr, labels=names, loc=2)
plt.show()
```

As can be seen below, the second legend I'm trying to add does not show the right colors, ie, 1 color per file read (top left corner):

[image]

I don't understand why the legend on the left doesn't show the right colors, since the color information is in each of the elements in the lineslr array:

```
linesclr[0].get_color()
Out[4]: 'r'
linesclr[0].get_color()
Out[5]: 'r'
linesclr[1].get_color()
Out[6]: 'b'
linesclr[2].get_color()
Out[7]: 'g'
```

Furthermore, I don't understand why the marker is not always the circle ('o') for all the keys in that legend.

***Solution I'm looking for:***

It occurs to me that the best way to convey the info on the plots is with the 2 legends, but with the legend on the right just showing the markers for each line for each device type (black line with corresponding marker), and the legend on the left showing the filenames and the colors (line with no markers) used for all the temperatures readings from that file.

So, I'd like to make the legend on the right just show the 4 thermocouple locations with their markers:

```
+ PCB
v FET1 
x FET2 
o FET3
```

and the legend on the left to show:  ACI50#5  in red, ACI50# in blue, ACI50#6 in green, an KDE5515 in cyan (or however many files I read in, each with its corresponding plot color).

I've tried reading and literature on matplotlib on legends and composing custom legends, and have looked for examples on the internet, but I'm not having much success understanding what I'm reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for :)

I think 2 solutions are possible:

In advance, sorry I had to sim data so the plot does not look like ordered lines but I think it is no problem anyway

1. With one legend for all files:

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import scipy.signal as sc
import numpy as np

dfs = [] # store df
cmap = cm.get_cmap('Set1')
cols = {}

for i, fn in enumerate(glob.glob("*.csv")) :
    #dfs.append(pd.read_csv(fn, header=0, usecols=[2,4,6,8], skiprows=12, names=['PCB', 'FET1', 'FET2', 'FET3'])) # Uncommenting this line to read from your files should work
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=['PCB', 'FET1', 'FET2', 'FET3'])) # Just random data
    cols[i] = cmap(i) # Maps one color to one file with a dict

mrks = {"PCB":'+',"FET1":'v',"FET2":'x',"FET3":'o'} # Maps one sensor to one marker type

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))
for n, d in enumerate(dfs) :
    ax.plot(sc.decimate(d['PCB'],5), ls='-', marker=mrks['PCB'], color=cols[n], label="PCB") # Use label to map to files
    ax.plot(sc.decimate(d['FET1'],5), ls='-', marker=mrks['FET1'], color=cols[n], label="FET1")
    ax.plot(sc.decimate(d['FET2'],5), ls='-', marker=mrks['FET2'], color=cols[n], label="FET2")
    ax.plot(sc.decimate(d['FET3'],5), ls='-', marker=mrks['FET3'], color=cols[n], label="FET3")

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Gives this plot:

[image: One legend for whole data]

2. With separated legends (sorry in my example I swapped the locations but you can adjust it easily

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import scipy.signal as sc
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

# create a marker for each thermocouple
mrks = {"PCB":'+',"FET1":'v',"FET2":'x',"FET3":'o'}
marker_legend = [Line2D([0], [0], lw=1, color="k", marker=v, label=k) for k, v in mrks.items()]
color_legend = []

dfs = [] # store df
cmap = cm.get_cmap('Set1')
cols = {}
for i, fn in enumerate(glob.glob("*.csv")) : # read files and map colors to each
    #dfs.append(pd.read_csv(fn, header=0, usecols=[2,4,6,8], skiprows=12, names=['PCB', 'FET1', 'FET2', 'FET3']))
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=['PCB', 'FET1', 'FET2', 'FET3']))
    cols[i] = cmap(i)
    color_legend.append(Line2D([0], [0], color=cmap(i), lw=1, label=fn))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))
for n, d in enumerate(dfs) :
    ax.plot(sc.decimate(d['PCB'],5), ls='-', marker=mrks['PCB'], color=cols[n])
    ax.plot(sc.decimate(d['FET1'],5), ls='-', marker=mrks['FET1'], color=cols[n])
    ax.plot(sc.decimate(d['FET2'],5), ls='-', marker=mrks['FET2'], color=cols[n])
    ax.plot(sc.decimate(d['FET3'],5), ls='-', marker=mrks['FET3'], color=cols[n])

first_legend = plt.legend(handles=marker_legend, loc="upper left")
ax = plt.gca().add_artist(first_legend)
second_legend = plt.legend(handles=color_legend, loc="upper right")

plt.show()
```

This is the resulting plot:

[image: Separated legends]

If you do not want to use a cmap from matplotlib you can still create a list of colors that you know will be longer than the number of files you will read and draw from it instead something like:

```py
cmap = ["r","g","b","cyan", ...]
...
for i, fn in enumerate(glob.glob("*.csv")) :
   ...
   cols[i] = cmap[i]
   ...
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.  I appreciate the multiple options to help me understand how to create the different legends.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Each plot drawn by the same call in the loop rewrites the legend, even though the data is different. Thus, you need to save them and then add them to the legend after no more overwrite is possible.

```
fig = plt.figure()
lines = []
colors=['r','b','g','c','m']
for i in range(len(filename)):
    l=plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['PCB'],5),'-+'+colors[i],label="PCB")
    lines=np.append(lines,l)
    l=plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET1'],5),'-v'+colors[i],label='FET1')
    lines=np.append(lines,l)
    l=plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET2'],5),'-x'+colors[i],label='FET2')
    lines=np.append(lines,l)
    l=plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET3'],5),'-o'+colors[i],label='FET3')
    lines=np.append(lines,l)

fig.legend(lines)
plt.show()
```

This will provide a `len(filename)*4` size legend with alternating colors. If you want to only give the colors per file, you can save one line per `i`.

```
fig = plt.figure()
lines = []
names = []
colors=['r','b','g','c','m']
for i in range(len(filename)):
    l=plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['PCB'],5),'-+'+colors[i],label="PCB")
    lines=np.append(lines,l)
    names=np.append(names, filename[i][0:7])
    plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET1'],5),'-v'+colors[i],label='FET1')
    plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET2'],5),'-x'+colors[i],label='FET2')
    plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET3'],5),'-o'+colors[i],label='FET3')

fig.legend(lines,labels=names)
plt.show()
```

---

**EDIT:** As a third option, you can also directly store the legend handles for the first line collection and set them later. For this to work correctly, you need to set others to have no legend. Assuming that you don't display these labels in your plot anyways, it is also an option.

```
lines = []
names = []
colors=['r','b','g','c','m']
for i in range(len(filename)):
    plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['PCB'],5),'-+'+colors[i],label="PCB")
    handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
    lines=np.append(lines,handles[0])
    names=np.append(names, filename[i][0:7])
    plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET1'],5),'-v'+colors[i],label='_nolegend_')
    plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET2'],5),'-x'+colors[i],label='_nolegend_')
    plt.plot(sc.decimate(x[i]['FET3'],5),'-o'+colors[i],label='_nolegend_')

plt.legend(lines,labels=names)
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you....for your second option, the legend indeed shows the filenames, but the markers and colors are wrong.....Based on the code you provided, I expected  lines to be a list of the PCB lines from each file. Instead, the legend shows all red lines, and a different marker for each fiename.   I don't understand why/how it is picking up the other markers (they should all be '+') when the only marker that is being stored should be the one from the PCB plot line...,  Also, how would I get rid of the "line2D" portion of each legend label from the first option? Thanks again.

Comment: ok, if change the "lines" assignment to " lines=np.append(lines,l[0].get_label())" I can just get back the "PCB", "FET1", "FET2", etc labels.  I think what I need to do is 2 legends, one that shows the markers indicating PCB,FET1, FET2, FET3, and another legend showing what colors go with what file.....

Comment: I put a third option to save the legend handles instead of linecollections. The line markers in the legend are all + now.