# creating a custom legend in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, label, legend

In trying to create a custom legend, I create an array of custom lines from which I want to extract the labels.

In a for loop, I create an array of custom_names like this:

```
custom_names=[custom_names, [Line2D([0],[0], color=colors[i], marker='None',label=filename[i][0:9])]]
```

I then try to use **Legend** to add this as a second, custom legend:

```
from matplotlib.legend import Legend
leg = Legend(ax, custom_names, loc='lower right')
ax.add_artist(leg)
```

this produces an error:

```
leg = Legend(ax, custom_names, loc='lower right')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'labels'
```

How do I extract the labels used in the creation of the custom_names array to use it in the Legend function(?) ?  Something like:

```
leg = Legend(ax, custom_names, custom_names.get_label(), loc='lower right')
```

but this doesn't work.

In fact, if I print custom_names, I get this:

```
print(custom_names)
[[[[], [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000021232E72BC8>]], [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000021232E83E08>]], [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000021232E8CE08>]]
```

What is "inside" the ['<'matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000021232E72BC8'>'] element, for instance?  How do I see or get access to the attributes used in the creation of that array element via the

```
custom_names=[custom_names, [Line2D([0],[0], color=colors[i], marker='None',label=filename[i][0:9])]]
```

statement?

I apologize if the question doesn't make sense. I'm struggling with calling things by their proper names (I am not a s/w guy).....I can try and clarify based on questions anyone raises about this question.

Comment: First of all, you would never create a legend through `matplotlib.legend.Legend`, but rather through `ax.legend(...)`. Then you need to obey to one of the possible signatures, `ax.legend(handles, labels)`, or `ax.legend(handles=handles)` depending on whether the handles have labels already or not.

Comment: I was following the example in https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.06-customizing-legends.html .     I need to customize a second legend in my plot, and am struggling extracting the color and label properties with which the "custom" lines were created.

Comment: A better version of that code would look [like this](https://gist.github.com/ImportanceOfBeingErnest/5e61287a6f63deb3a9f3da36c432124a) without using `matplotlib.legend.Legend`

Comment: Thank you, would you mind taking a look at what im trying to do here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60605911/matching-line-colors-to-legend-when-plotting-data-from-multiple-arrays?  I can’t seem to be able to control the markers and colors like I want.